# Calling Javascript function from C# Code behind using RegisterStartupScript w/ js file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, function, registerstartupscript

I'm having an issue getting the 2nd function in my js file to fire. The plan is to have 1 modal show during successful insert and the other if there are duplicate errors. The Success Modal works but if there is an error I still get the Success modal unless I comment out the code for it(testing). Then and only then does the 2nd function fire. I'm new to both C# and Javascript. Any help would be greatly appreciated. What am I missing????

Problem resolved with code below, but now I have a new issue. Duplicate error messages lol. When the error modal displays for the first time say with 1 error, it displays correctly. However, after entering known duplicate info into the 2nd tested field and submitted, the modal returns with the 2 errors as expected, but has also now duplicated the first as seen in the image attached.

[image]

I guess my question is how do I clear the bulleted list items from jquery on modal close?

**Code Behind** ** edited for working code

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con;
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection("connection string");
}

protected void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Create the command and set its properties
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "dupcheck";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    //Create the parameters and set their properties
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeviceType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = deviceTypeDL.SelectedItem.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeviceName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = devName.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeviceBrand", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = brand.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeviceModel", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = d_Model.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DevicePN", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = partNumber.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeviceSN", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = serialNumber.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeviceOS", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = operatingSystemDL.SelectedItem.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SPWAgent", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = spwAgentDL.SelectedItem.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeviceStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = statusDL.SelectedItem.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DepartmentAbbrev", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = departmentDL.SelectedItem.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = username.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@AircardModel", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = a_Model.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@IMEI_SN", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = imei_SN.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = phoneNumber.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@InsertSuccess_msg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
    cmd.Parameters["@InsertSuccess_msg"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeviceNameErr_msg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
    cmd.Parameters["@DeviceNameErr_msg"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeviceSnErr_msg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
    cmd.Parameters["@DeviceSnErr_msg"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@IMEI_SnErr_msg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
    cmd.Parameters["@IMEI_SnErr_msg"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNumberErr_msg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
    cmd.Parameters["@PhoneNumberErr_msg"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    //Excute Query
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    //Update Gridview or Display Error Messages
    GridView1.DataSourceID = "GridViewSource";
    GridView1.DataBind();

    String InsertSuccess_msg = cmd.Parameters["@InsertSuccess_msg"].Value.ToString();
    String DeviceNameErr_msg = cmd.Parameters["@DeviceNameErr_msg"].Value.ToString();
    String DeviceSnErr_msg = cmd.Parameters["@DeviceSnErr_msg"].Value.ToString();
    String IMEI_SnErr_msg = cmd.Parameters["@IMEI_SnErr_msg"].Value.ToString();
    String PhoneNumberErr_msg = cmd.Parameters["@PhoneNumberErr_msg"].Value.ToString();


        if (DeviceNameErr_msg != "")
        {
            ListItem listItem = new ListItem(DeviceNameErr_msg);
            ErrorBulletedList.Items.Add(listItem);
        }
        if (DeviceSnErr_msg != "")
        {
            ListItem listItem2 = new ListItem(DeviceSnErr_msg);
            ErrorBulletedList.Items.Add(listItem2);
        }
        if (IMEI_SnErr_msg != "")
        {
            ListItem listItem3 = new ListItem(IMEI_SnErr_msg);
            ErrorBulletedList.Items.Add(listItem3);
        }
        if (PhoneNumberErr_msg != "")
        {
            ListItem listItem4 = new ListItem(PhoneNumberErr_msg);
            ErrorBulletedList.Items.Add(listItem4);
        }
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "error_script", "ErrorMessageModal();", true);

        if (InsertSuccess_msg != "")
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "success_script", "SuccessfulInsertModal();", true);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Can't be sure, but I suspect it's because of the `else if`. If the first check is true (`InsertSuccess_msg != "" || InsertSuccess_msg != null`), the second check never happens. When you say commenting out the code for it, do you mean the entire first `if` block?

Comment: From your description, the whole javascript / registerStartupScript bit is irrelevant, you just have a logic error in your c#. How is InsertSucces_Msg initialized, and where in your asp.net page life cycle did you put the code fragment you posted here?

Comment: Additionally, C#'s string class has a convenient [`IsNullOrEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) method you might want to use instead of manually checking.

Comment: I'm forcing the first statement to be false to test for the second function which isn't firing and yes I comment out the first if and change the else to just and if and it fires. The insert doesn't happen either way and if the first statement is commented out it works as expected passing back the error from sql. Just not with the if statement.

Comment: By forcing I mean purposely entering duplicate data to get the error msg and null value for InsertSuccess_msg. I've also attached an image of the return value I receive in sql.

Comment: Something else to check: there is a difference between using [ScriptManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager(v=vs.100).aspx) and [ClientScriptManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager(v=vs.100).aspx). I'm not sure if your original registered script is cleared/unregistered on postback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to clear **ErrorBulletedList** at the beginning of **addBtn_Click** event.

For example,

```
protected void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ErrorBulletedList.Items.Clear();
    ...
}
```